# ASP.NET Core Web API update nuget package

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an ASP.NET Core Web API. I have one service and inside that I have two solutions `Data.sln` and `Data.Def.sln` in a single `AllData` Web API. This `Data.sln` has a reference to `Data.Def.sln`. The `Data.Def` services are installed in a nuget package of `Data.sln`. I have modified some code changes in the `Data.Def.sln` project solution.

The `Data.sln` project has the reference of `Data.Def` package version 1.1.0.12 that has the existing changes.

How can I update the nuget package with my code changes of the `Data.Def` solution project package in the `Data.sln`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think this issue is related to ASP.NET CORE or vs2022 ? Please help your needs in detail.